# CodeComplete в PhpStorm не догадывается какой тип объекта

Tags: phpstorm, code-style

Некоторые IDE, например, PHPEd успешно умеют парсить такую ситуацию и определять что находится в переменной $this->cat_api в методе actionIndex, чтобы активировать автоподсказки кода. Однако никак не могу добиться того же в phpStorm, несмотря на то, что даже явно подсказываю тип переменной через phpDoc.

Подскажите, все так мучаются или есть какая-то скрытая возможность заставить codeComplete работать лучше?

```
class Rss extends \RS\Controller\Front
{
    protected
        /**
         * @var \Article\Model\Catapi
         */
        $cat_api;

    /**
    * Инициализирует общие для всех действий переменные
    */
    function init()
    {
        $this->cat_api = new \Article\Model\Catapi();
        //Здесь подсказывает методы успешно
        $this->cat_api->.....
    }

    function actionIndex()
    {   
        // Как заставить phpStorm подсказывать методы здесь?
        // Он не понимает, что здесь объект \Article\Model\Catapi
        $this->cat_api->...
        //пишет No suggestions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где вы научились писать комментарии таким "изящным" способом?

```
protected
    /**
     * @var \Article\Model\Catapi
     */
    $cat_api;
```

Попробуйте документировать правильно:

```
/**
 * @var \Article\Model\Catapi
 */
protected $cat_api;
```

Так же я советую использовать автоматическую генерацию блоков PHPDoc: `Code -> Generate -> PHPDoc block`, если вы испытываете трудности с ручным написанием этих блоков.

Comment: Перепроверил, действительно помогло. Вот только не уверен, что phpStorm тут прав. Весь после ключевого слова protected может следовать несколько переменных, разделенных запятой. И это более приоритетный по качеству кода вариант.
В этом случае phpStorm получается не до конца поддерживает синтаксис PHP, как документировать переменные в строке protected $a, $b, $c; ?

Comment: @artpolt множественное определение свойств - это пример кода, который не соответствует стандартам PSR, поэтому "приоритетный по качеству кода вариант" - абсолютно неверное утверждение, вы откуда вообще это взяли? По возможности избегайте этого ;)

Comment: И все равно получается, что phpStorm не может без явной подсказки найти единственное присвоение значения свойству класса. Тот же PHPEd справляется с этой задачей и не требует подписывать @var. По сути PHPEd делает предположение относительно значения в переменной, которое в 99% оказывается верным.

Comment: @artpolt, не то вы нашли. "There MUST NOT be more than one property declared per statement.", читайте в разделе "4.2 Properties". Язык был создан задолго до принятых стандартов и старается сохранять обратную совместимость.